# InDesign: Table of Contents weird line-breaks

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I have been having troubles with my TOC, specifically, the header (Chapter Title) and subheader (Author) get separated in each page, even when there is space left for them.

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks to me that keep options are not properly set. Start by checking them out: title style should keep to next para while next para should not keep to next one but should keep all lines together. Or title style dont keep with anything and author para style keeps with previous one.

Answer (score -1):

I feel your pain this happens a lot with automatic table of contents (which is still awesome, but can be a pain when it wraps weird). I'd recommend pulling up the bottom of the text frame to make it wrap to the next page or insert a page break where you need it.
I hope this helps!

Comment: I had exactly the same thing the other day - Cheryl has the fix, edit once the contents are complete as manual line breaks don't stick when you update (or just pull-up frames)

Comment: But if you adjust the style of the title paragraph to (1) always keep all of its lines together and (2) always keep with the *next* paragraph, you don't have to manually fiddle!